# Github not showing correct CSS file

Tags: css, github-pages

The file structure in my GitHub repo is

```
--root
index.html
resume.css
--folder assets
    resume.css
```

(yes I made two identical css file just in case one of them works but none of them works...)
I tried to reference css file as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resume.css" media="all" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/resume.css" media="all" />
```

But again none of them works..
When I download the entire GitHub repo as a .zip file on my computer and unzippit, the website can display normally.
Is it something else I could do?

The webpage shows on my local file
[image]
and webpage on github
[image]

Comment: why are you calling `resume.css` if its called `style.css`? Or whats above is just an example?

Comment: My css file is named resume. thanks for pointing it out! Edited

Comment: Are you pushing to a specific branch? Or just to the main branch?

Comment: I have one branch and pushed to the main branch.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the GitHub page URL?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the CSS file.  https://prnt.sc/zuuU0Eg0CkrO

Comment: updated screenshot..

Comment: I use github pages to serve css and js to a remote site, and there are always caching issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check where you placed the `<link>` tag?
It should be inside the `<head>` tag

```
EDIT:
```

You can move highlighted section in [here](https://github.com/xinwei-zhuang/xinwei-zhuang.github.io/blob/main/index.html#:%7E:text=%3Ctitle%3EXinwei,min.css%22%3E) to parent `<head>` tag and remove `<head>` tag inside `<div>` tag

Comment: I did. I used two css file, one is linked as a webpage and works fine. The only one that github doesn't read is the local file. Since when I downloaded the folder and it shows correctly on my side, I'm assuming the syntax is not the problem.